# Realm NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable

Tags: android, realm

I am experiencing an issue that is pointed out in Realm's documentation:

> **Jackson Databind**
>
> Jackson Databind is a library for binding JSON data to Java classes.
>
> Jackson uses reflection to perform the data binding. This conflicts
>   with Realm’s support for RxJava, as RxJava might not be available to
>   the class loader. This can result in an exception that looks like
>   this:
>
> ```
> Copy to clipboardjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable
> at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
> ...
> ```

Here is the proposed fix:

> This can be fixed by either adding RxJava to your project or create
>   two empty dummy files that looks like the following.
>
> ```
> Copy to clipboard// File 1
> package io.reactivex;
>
> public class Flowable {
> }
>
>
> // File 2
> package io.reactivex;
>
> public class Observable {
> }
> ```
>
> This issue has also been reported to the Jackson project [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1070).

**Question: Where do I create the files so they don't have my app's package name?  (ex:  com.myApp.myPackage)**

Side note:  I'm experiencing this from SimpleXml, not Jackson (maybe simplexml uses jackson?).  I've seen 2 errors:

1. Realm NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable Realm
2. NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Observable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using Realm older than v4.0.0, so you need to create package `rx`, and the dummy class called `Observable`. But you just need to create it in `src/main/java/rx`.

```
package rx;

public class Observable {
}
```

For Realm 4.0.0+, you need in `src/main/java/io/reactivex`.

```
package io.reactivex;

public class Observable {
}
```

and

```
package io.reactivex;

public class Flowable {
}
```

and

```
package io.reactivex;

public enum BackpressureStrategy {
  MISSING,
  ERROR,
  BUFFER,
  DROP,
  LATEST
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I would recommend putting that "src/main/java/rx" in the doc for dumb-dumbs like me :P

Comment: Question:  This won't cause any issues with whatever lib is calling that class?

Comment: You're not using `asObservable()` anywhere, so it won't cause any problem unless you add RxJava1 to your project (in which case you'll have duplicate file), but you do not have RxJava1 and you probably won't considering it's been replaced with Rx2 since

Comment: was getting "NoClassDefFoundError: rx.Observable".  After doing what you said, I'm now getting "NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Observable"

Comment: ...what version of Realm is this again? XD if it's `4.0.0+` then you need `io.reactivex.Observable`, `io.reactivex.Flowable` and an enum called `io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy` which has a `LATEST` field.

Comment: going from 3.5 > 4.1.1

Comment: it looks like that did it!  Thank you!  In closing, please refer to my question about possible negative effects on the lib calling these methods

Comment: These are used only if you call `asFlowable()` or `asChangesetObservable()` anywhere, which you probably aren't.

Comment: now getting "NoSuchMethodError: No static method interval(JJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lrx/Observable; in class Lrx/Observable" but it looks like it's coming from another lib

Comment: Yeah, Realm only uses `Observable.create()`. In that case, you *will* need to add rxjava1 to your project, and remove `rx.Observable` dummy class, see  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/tree/1.x

Comment: if we remove realm (just done as a test, we're not actually going to remove it), these errors go away.  Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure what library you are using, but my guess is that they check if they can use RxJava or not by checking if `rx.Observable` exists, and if it does, then they try to use that, otherwise some different fallback mechanism.