# Android Firebase - Mysterious object keys

Tags: android, firebase, realm

I tried pushing an object, extended by RealmObject, to my Firebase Database. And then these key-value pairs appeared out of nowhere: "loaded", "managed", and "valid".

**User Object**

[image]

**Pushing User object to Firebase**

[image]

**Sample Firebase Database child**

[image: Sample Firebase Database child]

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sample.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.15'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My question is, where did those key-value pairs come from?

FYI:
I used the following dependecy to fix the issue that I encountered when pushing RealmObjects to Firebase.

```
 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.15'
```

Referring to this post:  [Crash combining Firebase and Realm - Failed resolution of: Lio/reactivex/Observable;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185420/crash-combining-firebase-and-realm-failed-resolution-of-lio-reactivex-observa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, where did those key-value pairs come from?

From `extends RealmObject`, of course:

> boolean   isLoaded()
>
> Checks if the query used to find this RealmObject
>   has completed.
>
> boolean   isManaged()
>
> Checks if this object is managed by Realm.
>
> boolean   isValid()
>
> Checks if the RealmObject is still valid to use
>   i.e., the RealmObject hasn't been deleted nor has the Realm been
>   closed.

Realm however provides the way to use `@RealmClass public class MyClass implements RealmModel` in place of `extends RealmObject` specifically for cases like this.

Comment: Just began using Realm + Firebase. Thanks, it works!